# How do I use python to auto-answer a pop-up prompt in Windows?

Tags: python

I use a ticketing program at work all day every day. Every 5 minutes it produces a little pop-up window asking "are you still using the program?" and if you don't click yes in 60 seconds it logs you out and closes the program. Very annoying.

I want to use Python (or whatever else works, I don't really care about the language) to make a script that detects when this window pops up and automatically presses the "yes I am still here" button on that window.

I believe that I can locate the pop-up window using Python's `subprocess` library and `win32gui` library. That is still a work in progress but if you think you have a better method I'm open to suggestions.

Once I do identify the pop-up window, what would be the best way to "click" the "yes I am still here" button? It would be nice if I could do this in the background milliseconds after the window is generated so that it's almost like the window never existed at all, but it's fine if I need to bring the window to the foreground and use something like x,y coordinates to simulate a click.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: I think this is what `pyautogui` is for.

Answer (score 0):

as @barmar said, https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ will help you.

You can take a screen shot and scale it to get the image file of the popup. Then, you can use some python code to locate the image and press the button.

```
ButtonLocation = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('bttnScshot.png')
ButtonPoint = pyautogui.center(ButtonLocation)
button7x, button7y = ButtonPoint
pyautogui.click(button7x, button7y)
```

Thank you for your time, I am new to
stackoverflow. :)